# View Binding extension function

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using the following extension function for View Binding in my adapters and in my custom views.

```
inline fun <T : ViewBinding> ViewGroup.viewBinding(crossinline bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Boolean) -> T) =
 bindingInflater.invoke(LayoutInflater.from(this.context), this, true)
```

```
val binding = viewBinding(ComponentButtonBinding::inflate)
```

For the custom views, it works fine, but for the adapters, I need the boolean in the invoke to be false. How could I fix this and make this function work for both?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just pass a boolean variable as well to the extension function. If you're primarily using `true` for it you might want to set the default value to `true`, but that's up to you.

```
inline fun <T : ViewBinding> ViewGroup.viewBinding(crossinline bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Boolean) -> T, attachToParent: Boolean = true) =
        bindingInflater.invoke(LayoutInflater.from(this.context), this, attachToParent)

val binding = viewBinding(ComponentButtonBinding::inflate)
val binding = viewBinding(ComponentButtonBinding::inflate, false)
```

Answer (score 5):

Extension function:

```
inline fun <T : ViewBinding> AppCompatActivity.viewBinding(
  crossinline bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater) -> T) =
    lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        bindingInflater.invoke(layoutInflater)
    }
```

Example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val binding by viewBinding(MainActivityBinding::inflate)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.button.onClick {
            showToast("hello world!")
        }
}
```

[More info](https://zhuinden.medium.com/simple-one-liner-viewbinding-in-fragments-and-activities-with-kotlin-961430c6c07c)